# Does Vatican participate in any International sports?

Tags: trivia, records, international-sports, participation

Does [Vatican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City) participate or ever participated in any international sports **as a country** ?

If participated I would like to know the details of some recent events.

Comment: Vatican is one of only two UN-recognized independent countries that [does not have a National Olympic Committee](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3943/1723).

Answer (score 11):

Vatican City has both a national [football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City_national_football_team) and [cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_Cricket_Team) team. However, as neither are members of the appropriate international governing body (FIFA and the ICC respectively) they don't compete in any form of regular competition, but instead play friendlies against other teams.

Comment: They are not members of ICC and FIFA means , Vatican does not want to be a part ? or ICC/FIFA wont allow Vatican to join them ?

Comment: I see no evidence that FIFA or the ICC wouldn't accept an application, so I suspect it's that they don't want to join.

Comment: wiki about Vatican's [FIFA Membership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City_national_football_team#FIFA_membership).